Keep putty from starting new lines at the top of the screen
I am using putty to connect to a device over a serial connection, 19200 baud rate.
Everything is fine and the data is showing ok, but every once in a while, sometimes after just a couple lines, sometimes after several, the screen "clears" and the next printed line is at the top of the screen.  It isn't actually clearing because I can scroll up to see the previous output, but instead of just continually adding new lines to the end it shifts everything so the newest line is at the top.
Is there a configuration option to change this?  I tried with the options in the Window configuration, like "Reset scrollback on display activity" but it is not what I'm looking for.

This behavior occurs on the ASCII form-feed character (aka FF, U+000C, control-L) and mimics the behavior of many printing terminals back when terminals were real things (often large, noisy, hot, and/or expensive) and not programs on a screen. I don't see any option to change it. You might try to convince the device not to send it.

i don't think it is coming from the device, a quick test using tera term and real term don't show the same behavior.
